# How to inject HTML into {0} of springMessageText in Velocity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization, velocity

I'm using Apache Velocity in an internationalized Spring MVC website.

I want to use "Redirecting in X seconds" as the phrase (message key) that my translators will translate.  The X will obviously be a variable number of seconds, and Javascript will update the page every second to count it down.

I thought I'd do this:

`#springMessageText("Redirecting in {0} seconds" ["<span class='seconds'>5</span>"])`

But this displays:

`Redirecting in <span class='seconds'>5</span> seconds`

(without parsing the HTML).

I **need** to be able to put the HTML tag in there because that is how javascript will know which part of the translated phrase to update.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

I created a custom macro file called custom.vm:

```
#macro( springMessageHtml $code, $args, $defaultValue)
    $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code, $args.toArray(), $defaultValue, false)
#end
```

In my velocity.properties file, I changed this line to reference it:
`velocimacro.library=org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/spring.vm,/velocity/custom.vm`

And now in my views (like sample.vm), I can call it like:
`#springMessageHtml("Redirecting in {0} seconds" ["<span class='seconds'>5</span>"])`

OLDER ANSWER:

I found an answer here: http://feima2011.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/misc-notes/

```
#set($args = ["<span class='seconds'>5</span>"])
            $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage("Redirecting in {0} seconds",     
$args.toArray(), "", false)
```

`#springMessageText` is just a macro that calls $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage() anyway; by calling it directly, I'm able to specify that last parameter (a boolean for whether to escape the HTML).

Now I'm able to have unescaped HTML.  Maybe eventually I'll code a new macro called `#springMessageHtml`, and it will call $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage() with the escapeHtml parameter set to False.  Then in my view, I'd only need 1 line of code.